# What is needed to perform an authenticated raw HTTP request to Drupal 7?

Tags: http, authentication, drupal, request, postman

I am trying to prepare an external script in PHP or Python (or even in pure Bash using `curl` if it does not require a lot of extra work) that will successfully perform an authenticated HTTP request to a Drupal page accessible only to an authenticated user.

**To know what such a raw HTTP request should look like, I'm first trying to perform such a raw HTTP request using Postman.**

**I set up:**

- **request method as GET**,
- **correct URL address**,
- **all headers identically to those in the browser** (I copy them using the developer tool when I am logedin as *admin*) **including current cookies containing the current session key with its value**.

In the browser I have the status of 200 and the page is displayed correctly, but **in Postman, unfortunately I receive the status of 403 Forbidedden**.

**What should I do to make this HTTP request work properly like in the browser?**

Comment: Hi, did you eventually figured out a better way to perform authenticated browser-like requests (without using services) ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will need to perform 2 queries to make it work like in the browser :

- `GET /user/login` to parse the document and grab user-login `form_build_id`, eg.

  ```
  <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-IJkfUfaubS...OsWXBsw">
  ```
- `POST /user/login` with at least this header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the following form data :

  - `form_build_id : <form_build_id>`
  - `name : <username>`
  - `pass : <password>`
  - `form_id : user-login`

Once authenticated, you should get a session cookie (see the "Cookies" button in Postman), using this cookie in the next requests you should be able to get private content.